# How to make a button and a text input full width (for modern browsers)

Tags: html, layout, html-input

This seems like the most basic thing in the world, yet no amount of Googling or experimenting leads me to the simple solution that must exist.

```
<div>
  <input type="button" value="look up"/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="word to search for">
</div>
```

I expect the "look up" button to be on the left just the right size to fit its text, and the text input to fill the rest of the width of the div. But instead the text input takes a seemingly arbitrary width.

I want to know only the minimal answer for modern browsers only, preferably with only inline styles if possible, and preferably without resorting to tables.

(It's just for personal code nobody will ever see and to help me to learn some of the basics. Searching brings up tons of chaff and inspecting websites it's hard to find what is minimal since they use tons of styling.)